# Is the type of a function affected by the presence or absence of a function parameter pack in its parameter-declaration-clause?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, c++20

Consider the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

void f(int);
void g(auto ...);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f), decltype(g<int>)>); // succeeds in GCC 12.1, Clang 14.0.0, and MSVC 19.30
```

[[dcl.fct]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct-12) specifies that the parameter-type-list of a function is part of the function type (obviously):

> The return type, the **parameter-type-list**, the *ref-qualifier*, the *cv-qualifier-seq*, and the exception specification, but not the default arguments or the trailing *requires-clause*, are part of the function type.

The last sentence of [[dcl.fct]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct-5) specifies that the "presence or absence of ... a function parameter pack" is part of the function's *parameter-type-list*:

> The resulting list of transformed parameter types and the **presence or absence of** the ellipsis or **a function parameter pack** is the function's *parameter-type-list*.

Since the non-template function `f` has no function parameter pack in its parameter list but variadic function template `g` does, would that not mean that their parameter-type-lists are different, and therefore their types are also?

Comment: _but variadic function template g does (have a parameter pack)_ But does it?  All the big three compilers don't appear to agree with you.  Anyway, it's an interesting question (and I don't know the answer), so I added a couple of tags which should attract the big guns.

Comment: `g<int>` stamps out the function `void g(int)`. that is the same as `f`.

Comment: See, told you so :)

Answer (score 1):

> Since the non-template function `f` has no function parameter pack in its parameter list but variadic function template `g` does, would that not mean that their parameter-type-lists are different, and therefore their types are also?

`g` is an [Abbreviated Function Template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template). Being a template, it doesn't have a type of its own.

`g<int>`, on the other hand, is an *instantiation* of `g`. It produces a concrete function `void g(int)`, which has the same type as `f`.

Comment: So the "concrete" specialization `g<int>` is not considered to have a function parameter pack? How then could any function ever have a parameter pack as part of its type?

Comment: No, the final `void g(int)` function that `g<int>` produces does not have a parameter-pack, the parameter-pack has already been expanded by the compiler. A concrete function type can never have a parameter-pack, AFAICS. Only a template can have a parameter-pack, and a template is not a type.

Comment: Interesting. I would think, in reading [the last sentence of \[dcl.fct\]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5.sentence-5), that there must be _some_ way that a function parameter pack could be considered "present" for the purpose of determining a parameter-type-list. Otherwise, what's the point of mentioning it there?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Ask the language lawyers

Comment: @TSmith The function parameter pack is part of the template.  If you had two templates, you could compare them and the packs or lack thereof will be part of the function template's signature.  Once you use `g<int>`, there is no more pack, just a single `int` parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand that a pack is part of the function template _signature_, but what about a function _type_? My interpretation of the aforementioned standardese is that their presence/absence is also (somehow) part of the function type.

Comment: @NathanOliver On second thought... I guess a pack is included in the definition of a _parameter-type-list_ for the purpose of defining a function template signature, but simply not for a function type. Even though it's still technically included in the latter, it would always be considered absent, so it is relevant only for the former. Does that sound right (or make any sense)?

Comment: @TSmith That's the way I understand it.